# DataRow and the protected internal constructor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, datatable, datarow

How can a DataTable create a new instance of a DataRow with the NewRow method if the constructor of the DataRow class is protected internal and DataTable doesn't inherit from DataRow?

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // error: inaccessible due to its protection level
        DataRow dr = new DataRow(); 

        // works
        DataRow dr = new DataTable().NewRow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`protected internal` means "accessible by derived classes" and "accessible by other classes in the same assembly". `DataTable` and `DataRow` are in the same assembly, so `DataTable` has access to all of `DataRow`'s internal members.

Comment: protected internal means "accessible by derived classes in the same assembly", but DataTable is not derived from DataRow.

Comment: No, `protected internal` means what I said it means. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hope you already got an answer for this.

But still I am adding my answer to this to address “Why it is designed in this way”.

As **“hvd” mentioned** they are in same assembly that’s why DataTable able to create instance of DataRow.

**The reason for this approach is:**

• Data row contains values for each column
• Ideally an array internally used to store these values

• So each data row contains array which contains values

• But data row will not be knowing the size of the array to initialize

• Which depends on number of columns in the data table

• But data table knows how many columns in the table

• That’s why it takes responsibility to create OR set the array size of the DataRow